# asynctask variables problems

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

i am struglling a bit with my varibles in my asynctask routine i am writing for the moment

my code:

```
package com.example.deceunincktechniekers;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.client.*;
import org.apache.http.*;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class BTWcontrole extends Activity 
{

TextView btwuitvoer;
EditText landcode;
EditText nummer;
Button verstuur;
String land;
String num;
String antwoord;
Context btwcontrolecontext;
String jsonData;
private String bedrijfsnaam = new String();
String zoekurl = "http://www.softnaert.be/SNWebservices/SNWeb.wso/checkVat/JSON";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.btwcontrole);
        btwcontrolecontext = this;
    btwuitvoer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultaat);
    verstuur = (Button) findViewById(R.id.controleer);
    landcode = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.landcode);
    nummer = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.btwnr);

verstuur.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    btwopvragen loaderTask = new btwopvragen();
    loaderTask.execute();

    land = landcode.getText().toString();
    num = nummer.getText().toString();
    Log.i("bedrijfsnaam in onclick", bedrijfsnaam);
    btwuitvoer.setText(bedrijfsnaam);   
}   
});};

public void onTaskComplete(){
    Log.i("bedrijfsnaam ontaskcomplete", bedrijfsnaam);

}

   private class btwopvragen extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

ProgressDialog dialog;

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    dialog = new ProgressDialog(btwcontrolecontext);
    dialog.setTitle("btwnummer ophalen");
    dialog.show();
    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    // toegevoegde code om parameters aan de code toe te voegen
    if(!zoekurl.endsWith("?")){
            zoekurl += "?";
    };

    List<NameValuePair> parameters = new LinkedList<NameValuePair>();
    parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("llcountryCode", String.valueOf(land)));
    parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("llvatNumber", String.valueOf(num)));

    String parameterString = URLEncodedUtils.format(parameters, "utf-8");


    // effectieve http request met de parameters toegevoegd
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet aanvraag = new HttpGet(zoekurl + parameterString);


    // foutanalyse van de http request
    try
    {
        HttpResponse antwoord = client.execute(aanvraag);
        StatusLine statuslijn = antwoord.getStatusLine();
        int statuscode = statuslijn.getStatusCode();
        if(statuscode != 200){
            return null;
        }

        InputStream jsonStream = antwoord.getEntity().getContent();
        BufferedReader reader= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(jsonStream));
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        String lijn;

        while((lijn = reader.readLine())!= null){
            builder.append(lijn);

        }

        jsonData = builder.toString();
        // met de volgende lijn is de data zichtbaar in de logcat
        Log.i("btw geretourneerde data", jsonData);

        // hier beginnen we met de json data te ontmantelen
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonData);
        String bedrijfsnaam = json.getString("sCompanyName"); 
        Log.i("bedrijfsnaam in asynctask", bedrijfsnaam);


    }
    catch (ClientProtocolException e){

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e){

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (JSONException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return null;
}   
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    Log.i("bedrijfsnaam in onpostexecute", bedrijfsnaam);   
    dialog.dismiss();
    super.onPostExecute(result);

    }


}


}
```

my logcat:

```
    08-11 14:22:45.160: I/Choreographer(6532): Skipped 42 frames!  The application may        be doing too much work on its main thread.
    08-11 14:22:45.439: I/Choreographer(6532): Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
    08-11 14:22:45.649: I/Choreographer(6532): Skipped 39 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
    08-11 14:22:45.849: I/Choreographer(6532): Skipped 50 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
    08-11 14:22:46.019: I/Choreographer(6532): Skipped 44 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
    08-11 14:22:46.209: I/Choreographer(6532): Skipped 47 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
    08-11 14:22:46.329: I/Choreographer(6532): Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
    08-11 14:22:46.479: I/Choreographer(6532): Skipped 38 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
   08-11 14:22:46.629: I/Choreographer(6532): Skipped 39 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
  08-11 14:22:46.699: I/btw geretourneerde data(6532): {  "eTransferStatus": 0,  "bValid": true,  "sLand": "be",  "sBtwNr": "0420347421",  "sCompanyName": "BVBA SOFT - NAERT",  "sCompanyAdres": "MARIASTRAAT 4\n8870  IZEGEM",  "sTransferError": "",  "sFaultCode": "",  "sFaultString": "",  "sErr": "",  "dDateChecked": "2013-08-11"}
   08-11 14:22:46.699: I/bedrijfsnaam in asynctask(6532): BVBA SOFT - NAERT
   08-11 14:22:46.779: I/Choreographer(6532): Skipped 36 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
   08-11 14:22:46.959: I/Choreographer(6532): Skipped 43 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
   08-11 14:23:10.299: I/Choreographer(6532): Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing     too much work on its main thread.
```

the problem is i cannot use my variable bedrijfsnaam in my oncreate method, i putted 4 lines in different places to make the bedrijfsnaam variable visible in my logcat and only one seems to be logging.

what can be the reason for that?

Comment: pay attention to this error before you do anything else `The application may be doing too much work on its main thread`

Comment: doesn't seem to solve my problem

Comment: you can make asynctask an inner class of your activity. declare `bedrijfsnaam` as a class member.

Comment: can you give me an example of that? i just tried already so much i don't know anymore which is what

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was able to solve my question by [this video](http://youtu.be/t988JQHDbX0)

my biggest mistake was that i didn't added the statement "return bedrijfsnaam" to my assynctask

hope i helped some guys out with this answer

Answer (score 0):

*I didnt tested this code. But i made some changes in Asyntask. your already initialise the String globally. I dont no why you declare once more. In this code i modified for after the completion of doinBackground method. and executing the onPostExecution method UI will update.

```
public class BTWcontrole extends Activity {

TextView btwuitvoer;
EditText landcode;
EditText nummer;
Button verstuur;
String land;
String num;
String antwoord;
Context btwcontrolecontext;
String jsonData;
private String bedrijfsnaam = new String();
String zoekurl = "http://www.softnaert.be/SNWebservices/SNWeb.wso/checkVat/JSON";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.btwcontrole);
    btwcontrolecontext = this;
    btwuitvoer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultaat);
    verstuur = (Button) findViewById(R.id.controleer);
    landcode = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.landcode);
    nummer = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.btwnr);

    verstuur.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            btwopvragen loaderTask = new btwopvragen();
            loaderTask.execute();

        }
    });
};

public void onTaskComplete() {
    Log.i("bedrijfsnaam ontaskcomplete", bedrijfsnaam);

}

private class btwopvragen extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    ProgressDialog dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(btwcontrolecontext);
        dialog.setTitle("btwnummer ophalen");
        dialog.show();
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // toegevoegde code om parameters aan de code toe te voegen
        if (!zoekurl.endsWith("?")) {
            zoekurl += "?";
        }
        ;

        List<NameValuePair> parameters = new LinkedList<NameValuePair>();
        parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("llcountryCode", String
                .valueOf(land)));
        parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("llvatNumber", String
                .valueOf(num)));

        String parameterString = URLEncodedUtils
                .format(parameters, "utf-8");

        // effectieve http request met de parameters toegevoegd
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet aanvraag = new HttpGet(zoekurl + parameterString);

        // foutanalyse van de http request
        try {
            HttpResponse antwoord = client.execute(aanvraag);
            StatusLine statuslijn = antwoord.getStatusLine();
            int statuscode = statuslijn.getStatusCode();
            if (statuscode != 200) {
                return null;
            }

            InputStream jsonStream = antwoord.getEntity().getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(jsonStream));
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            String lijn;

            while ((lijn = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                builder.append(lijn);

            }

            jsonData = builder.toString();
            // met de volgende lijn is de data zichtbaar in de logcat
            Log.i("btw geretourneerde data", jsonData);

            // hier beginnen we met de json data te ontmantelen
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonData);
            bedrijfsnaam = json.getString("sCompanyName");
            Log.i("bedrijfsnaam in asynctask", bedrijfsnaam);

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        Log.i("bedrijfsnaam in onpostexecute", bedrijfsnaam);
        dialog.dismiss();

        land = landcode.getText().toString();
        num = nummer.getText().toString();
        Log.i("bedrijfsnaam in onclick", bedrijfsnaam);
        btwuitvoer.setText(bedrijfsnaam);

        super.onPostExecute(result);

    }

}}
```

Comment: the gettext() of land and num need to be in my onclick method, otherwise the parameters for my httprequest cannot be filled out, but annyway, it gives me always the same result, nothing on btwuitvoer.settext

Comment: Are you using Json parser?

Comment: verstuur.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    land = landcode.getText().toString();
    num = nummer.getText().toString();
    Btwopvragen loaderTask = new Btwopvragen(land,num);
    loaderTask.execute();

   }
  });
 };private String land;
  private String num;
  
  public Btwopvragen(String land, String num){
   this.land = land;
   this.num = num;
  }

Comment: i tried the code you suggest in the remark here and i get 732 errors by eclipse,i kept on searching a little bit for the problem, the variable seems only to be available in my doinbackgroud routine, declared as "protected Void doInBackground" isn't it possible the protected holds my variable? how to handle that?

Comment: i've found out i need to use a synchronisation between my UI thread and my asynctask, what is the best way to set something like this up?